# Can't find "Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens"

Tags: java, processing

I am writing an implementation of Dijkstra's Algorithm for a project using Processing, and I keep getting the error "Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens", without any indication of which file the error is in, or where in the file it is, and I can't for the life of me find where the issue is.

Any help would be appreciated.

LargeGraph.pde:

```
ArrayList<Vertex> vertices;
ArrayList<Edge> edges;

void setup() {
  size(1000, 1000);
  vertices = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
  edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
  randomSeed(22);
  fillVertices();
  fillEdges();
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  stroke(255);

  for (Vertex v : vertices) {
    if (vertices.indexOf(v) == 7) {
      fill(255, 0, 0);  
    }
    circle((v.x + 1) * 19, (v.y + 1) * 19, 10);
    fill(255);
  }

  for (Edge e : edges) {
    line((e.v1.x + 1) * 19, (e.v1.y + 1) * 19, (e.v2.x + 1) * 19, (e.v2.y + 1) * 19); 
  }

  calculateSPT(vertices.get(0));
  println(getShortestPathTo(vertices.get(7)));
}

class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex> {
  int x, y, id, csf;
  double minDistance;
  Vertex previous;

  Vertex (int num, int xpos, int ypos) {
    minDistance = 999999999999999999999999999999.;
    id = num;
    x = xpos;
    y = ypos;
    csf = 0;
  }

  ArrayList<Edge> adjacencies() {
    ArrayList<Edge> adjacencies = new ArrayList<Edge>();

    for (Edge e : edges) {
      if (e.v1.equals(this)) {
        adjacencies.add(e);  
      }
    }

    return adjacencies;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Vertex other) {
    if (this.csf > other.csf) {
      return 1;  
    } else if (this.csf == other.csf) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  }
}

class Edge {
  Vertex v1;
  Vertex v2;
  int weight;

  Edge(Vertex v, Vertex v0, int w) {
    v1 = v;
    v2 = v0;
    weight = w;
  }
}

void fillEdges() {
  // for each vertex pick a random number 2-5 and generate an edge
  // to a random vertex with a weight based on its distance in space
  // times a random factor

  for (Vertex v : vertices) {
    int numEdges = 1; //round(random(2, 5));
    //for (int i = 0; i < numEdges; i++) {
      Vertex vertex = vertices.get(round(random(0, 9)));
      if (vertex.equals(v)) {
        vertex = vertices.get(round(random(0, 9)));
      }
      int weight = int(dist(v.x, v.y, vertex.x, vertex.y) * random(0, 2));

      edges.add(new Edge(v, vertex, weight));
    //}
  }
}

void fillVertices() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int x = round(random(0, 50));
    int y = round(random(0, 50));

    vertices.add(new Vertex(i, x, y));
  }
}
```

Dijkstra.pde:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.PriorityQueue<E>;

void calculateSPT(Vertex start) {  
  start.minDistance = 0.;
  PriorityQueue<Vertex> vertexQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
  vertexQueue.add(start);

  while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
    Vertex u = vertexQueue.poll();

    for (Edge e : u.adjacencies()) {
      Vertex v = e.v2;
      int weight = e.weight;
      double costSoFar = u.minDistance + weight;
      if (costSoFar < v.minDistance) {
        vertexQueue.remove(v);

        v.minDistance = costSoFar;
        v.previous = u;
        vertexQueue.add(v);
      }
    }
  }
}

ArrayList<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Vertex target) {
  ArrayList<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
  for (Vertex v = target; v != null; v = v.previous) {
    path.add(v);  
  }

  Collections.reverse(path);
  return path;
}
```

Comment: This is a ton of code to ask us to debug for you. Why don't you try starting with a [mcve] and only adding code until you see the error? That will tell you what caused it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it - the problem was line 2 of Dijkstra.pde.  The import should be `java.util.PriorityQueue`, not `java.util.PriorityQueue<E>`.